# How to convert webclient response to ResponseEntity?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am able to convert WebClient response to Response Entity with `exchange()` method which is deprecated now.

Please suggest other way of achieving the same result. Below is my code.

```
public ResponseEntity<TestClass> getTestDetails() {
            ClientResponse clientResponse = webClientBuilder.build()
                    .get()
                    .uri("http://localhost:9090/test")
                    .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                        httpHeaders.add(Constants.ACCEPT, Constants.APPLICATION_JSON);
                        })
                    .exchange()
                    .block();
            
            return clientResponse.toEntity(TestClass.class).block();
}
```

Comment: its in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-exchange

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring WebFlux 5.3.0 - WebClient.exchangeToMono()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650820/spring-webflux-5-3-0-webclient-exchangetomono)

Answer (score 5):

I did it in the following way:

```
   public ResponseEntity<TestClass> getTestDetails() {
        return webClientBuilder.build()
                .get()
                .uri("http://localhost:9090/test")
                .headers(httpHeaders -> {
                    httpHeaders.add(Constants.ACCEPT, Constants.APPLICATION_JSON);
                    })
                .retrieve()
                .toEntity(TestClass.class)
                .block();
    }
```