# WebClient exchangeToMono retrieving empty body

Tags: spring, spring-webflux, webflux

When using **WebClient**'s `exchangeToMono()` the body retrieving part is always returning an empty Mono:

Example, the exposed service *which returns a non-empty Mono*

```java
@PostMapping("/test")
public Mono<Pojo> getCalled(@RequestBody Pojo pojo) {
    System.out.println(pojo); // always prints a non-null object
    return Mono.just(pojo);
}
```

WebClient with `.retrieve()`

```java
WebClient.create().post().uri(theUrl).bodyValue(p).retrieve().toEntity(Pojo.class).map(response -> {
    if (response.getStatusCode().isError()) {
        // do something;
    }
    return response.getBody();
}).single(); // always get a single element and does not fail
```

WebClient with `.exchangeToMono()`

```java
WebClient.create().post().uri(theUrl).bodyValue(p).exchangeToMono(Mono::just).flatMap(response -> {
    if (response.statusCode().isError()) {
        // do something;
    }

    return response.bodyToMono(Pojo.class).single(); // fails with java.util.NoSuchElementException: Source was empty
});
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: why are you doing `.exchangeToMono(Mono::just)` and then flatMapping straight after? it makes no sense at all, just do `.exchangeToMono(response -> ...)` and handle your response inside the exchangeToMono function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i have no idea why you are doing `exchangeToMono(Mono::just).flatMap(response -> ...)` as it makes no sense.

No you don't need to consume the `Mono` twice, what you need is to read the documentation on how to use the exchange function properly [WebClient > Exchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web-reactive.html#webflux-client)

Here is the example taken from the docs

```
Mono<Person> entityMono = client.get()
        .uri("/persons/1")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .exchangeToMono(response -> {
            if (response.statusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) {
                return response.bodyToMono(Person.class);
            }
            else {
                // Turn to error
                return response.createException().flatMap(Mono::error);
            }
        });
```

And here is your code, but doing the things in the `exchangeToMono` instead

```
WebClient.create().post().uri(theUrl).bodyValue(p).exchangeToMono(response -> {
    if (response.statusCode().isError()) {
        // do something;
    }

    return response.bodyToMono(Pojo.class).single();
});
```

`exchangeToMono` has a purpose, its not there to just put stuff into a `Mono<T>` its there because you need to consume the `response` so that the server can release the connection that has been allocated. You do that by doing your checks etc in the `exchangeToMono` and then extract the body to a `Mono<T>`.

Comment: Great answer. I was not exactly doing `exchangeToMono(Mono::just).flatMap(response -> ...)` , but `exchangeToMono(Mono::just).elapsed().flatMap(durationAndResponse -> ...)` so with `durationAndResponse` I could print time elapsed, print response status, and (if needed) end with `return response.createException().flatMap(Mono::error);`, which inside had the response body for logging purposes. Now I understand if I don't read the body inside the exchangeToMono it would be to late.

Comment: also i have already answered this question sort of here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64650820/spring-webflux-5-3-0-webclient-exchangetomono and i can only answer questions in regards to the code presented. If the code is not in the question, the answer is what it is.

Answer (score 1):

The response `Mono` is empty because it has already been consumed by `.exchangeToMono`,  thus `single()` operator fails with `NoSuchElementException` as expected.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Is there a way to consume it twice?
Strange thing is in the `exchangeToMono()` case if I call `response.createException()` the same method is executted, parsed as byte[] and (in the end) the body is retrieved.

Comment: @Fradantim you can not consume it twice. Put your logic inside `exchangeToMono` instead.